# Change the href

Tags: html, laravel

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="ClientPage/{{ $client->id }}"> View</a>
http://localhost:9090/S2/public/VLead/ClientPage/17
```

but the right one should be

```
http://localhost:9090/S2/public/ClientPage/17
```

so i need to remove VLead from the href one I'm clicking 
id }}"> View

Comment: use the `url()` helper method to generate the url `href = "{{ url('ClientPage/'.$client->id) }}"`

Comment: It's work Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are on the `VLead` page. If you use `href="ClientPage/{{ $client->id }}"` it will keep the current page in the url aswell. Change the href to `/public/ClientPage/{{ $client->id }}` to fix this problem.

And like [@linktoahref](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808894/linktoahref) pointed out i suggest you use the [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url) or [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) function